# Can you 'kill' to the end of a line in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

In Unix-y editors, you can often press CTRL-k (kill) to delete everything after the text caret position on the current line.

Is there an equivalent "single action" in the Visual Studio 2008 text editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Tools|Customize look at the Commands tab. There is a Delete to EOL command. You can drag it to a toolbar. Also you can assign a shortcut key.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> , <kbd>Delete</kbd> is the only thing I can think of.  You could macro-ize this, I suspect.

Comment: and assign Ctrl+K to the macro!

Comment: That may not be the best idea, since CTRL+K is the beginning of a chorded keyboard command in VS... You'd lose a lot of other functionality (like my favorite CTRL+K,CTRL+C to commentize a block of code).

Comment: Also, here's a list of keyboard shortcuts for VS: http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx